# php dynamically creating a file on form submit

Tags: php, html

would any one know how to automatically create a file through PHP so when the  tag is clicked it also have the file right now it's only a path which is displayed through a loop. but when you click it there is no file, of course, long story short how can I also create a file too with a loop so all links have files created through fopen or something,  just like all of them have paths generated.

```
<?php
function display_user_docs($doc_array) {


  // set global variable, to test later if this is on the page
  global $doc_table;
  $doc_table = true;
?>
  <br>
  <form name="doc_table" action="delete_doc.php" method="post">
  <table width="300" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
  <?php
  $color = "#cccccc";
  echo "<tr bgcolor=\"".$color."\"><td><strong>Documentations</strong></td>";
  echo "<td><strong>Delete?</strong></td></tr>";
  if ((is_array($doc_array)) && (count($doc_array) > 0)) {
    foreach ($doc_array as $doc)  {
      if ($color == "#cccccc") {
        $color = "#ffffff";
      } else {
        $color = "#cccccc";
      }

      echo "<tr bgcolor=\"".$color."\"><td><a class=\"all-doc-link\" href=\"".$doc.".php\">".htmlspecialchars($doc)."</a></td>
            <td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"del_me[]\"
                value=\"".$doc."\"></td>
            </tr>";
    }
  } else {
    echo "<tr><td>No documentation on record</td></tr>";
  }
?>
  </table>
  </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: maybe this helps. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Comment: yeah, but where an how to insert it in the loop so they make every new file according to its path in the loop.

Comment: You do not use `global` - that indicates bad code in 99,99% cases

Comment: Use a database instead, this way searching the documentation will be a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `file_put_contents` to create a file in PHP.

It takes two parameters, the first of which is the name of the file to create, and the second of which is the contents to put inside of the file.

For example, if I wanted to make a file called `123.txt` which contains `hello world`, I would do the following:

```
file_put_contents("123.txt", "hello world");
```

The filename can contain slashes `/`, so that you can specify which folder to create the file in. Thus, if I wanted to make my `123.txt` file in the folder `abc`, I can put `abc/123.txt` as the filename (as long as `abc` is in the same folder as the PHP script).

You can find more about `file_put_contents` in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).